# What's Spanish for "soul patch"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, solicitud-de-término

En mi curro, cada mes de noviembre algunos se suman al [Movember](https://us.movember.com/).

> Movember is an annual event involving the growing of moustaches during the month of November to raise awareness of men's health issues, such as prostate cancer, testicular cancer, and men's suicide. The Movember Foundation runs the Movember charity event, housed at Movember.com
>
> Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movember)

Tras dejarse crecer la barba durante un mes, a veces hacen cosas ingeniosas o divertidas al llegar diciembre, cuando empiezan a afeitarse. Uno de ellos por ejemplo se la ha ido quitando "por partes", desde una barba espesa hasta estar completamente afeitado pasando por perilla, bigotes de motorista, bigote normal, etc.

Decía que había pensado en dejarse un "Soul patch" que es

> a small patch of facial hair just below the lower lip and above the chin
>
> source: más [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soul_patch)

[image: un muñeco con soul patch]

¿Cómo se llama en español este tipo de barba que es solo un poco de vello facial entre el labio inferior y la barbilla?

Comment: No tenía ni idea de este movimiento hasta la semana pasada que se pasaron por mi oficina recaudando euros y repartiendo galletas con forma de bigote. Pensaba que era algo local, de alguna organización de aquí, luego me entero de que es algo que se hace en toda España y ahora me entero de que es internacional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se llama [**mosca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Pt3ozF8):

> 2. f. Pelo que nace al hombre entre el labio inferior y el comienzo de la barba, y que algunos dejan crecer aun no llevando perilla.

Según el [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle), aparece por primera vez en el diccionario de Gaspar y Roig de 1855, mientras que en el diccionario de la RAE figura desde la edición de 1884.

Igualmente aparece, por ejemplo, en el [**Wikcionario**](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mosca), acepción 2ª:

> Barba pequeña que se deja sólo bajo el labio inferior y que no incluye el mentón.